# Apache; Invalid command 'DavLockDB'

Tags: php, mysql, apache

Just learning about PHP and MySQL. Attempting to enable PHP on Mac Mini. I've followed several thread regarding this, but have not found a solution.

Terminal Output:

```
Jessicas-Mac-mini:~ jessicaclark$ php -v
PHP 5.5.14 (cli) (built: Sep  9 2014 19:09:25) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
Jessicas-Mac-mini:~ jessicaclark$ cd /etc/apache2/
Jessicas-Mac-mini:apache2 jessicaclark$ sudo nano httpd.conf
Password:
Jessicas-Mac-mini:apache2 jessicaclark$ sudo apachectl restart
Password:
Jessicas-Mac-mini:apache2 jessicaclark$ httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.9 (Unix)
Server built:   Sep  9 2014 14:48:20
Jessicas-Mac-mini:apache2 jessicaclark$ apachectl configtest
AH00526: Syntax error on line 15 of /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-dav.conf:
Invalid command 'DavLockDB', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Supposed to be able to open http://localhost/
with 'It works!'...Any feedback appreciated!

Comment: And what do you want fron us? Imagine your `httpd-dav.conf`?

Comment: I am sorry but I am not sure what that means? I cannot locate that file...I am really just looking to be pointed into the right direction....

Comment: Isn't it in `/private/etc/apache2/extra/`?

Comment: By default, the line in OSX's `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` that contains `Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-dav.conf` is commented out (prefixed by `#`).  Why have you uncommented it?  Do you want to use Apache's WebDAV module?  If so, you'll also need to uncomment the relevant `LoadModule` directives (which are listed atop the included file).

Comment: This is how my file looks: is this correct? I really appreciate your help!         # Various default settings
#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-default.conf

Comment: Used this site to help solve my problem: http://www.thermalexposure.com/2014/11/14/fix-broken-apache-config-after-upgrading-to-os-x-yosemite/